# XCode error when building the Kotlin MPP iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to follow the example [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/06_SettingUpKotlinFramework) of building a native cross-platform mobile app in Kotlin. (I've linked to the step I'm having issues with, but I'm using the master branch of the linked repo which should contain ready-to-build code)

The Android version builds fine and I am able to simulate it, but I'm having issues with building the iOS app on Xcode. When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KotlinIOS-ektaeprzdqunqygjxzrkmpdfyoyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/KotlinIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinIOS.build/Script-47729E7122F480EB00B9B36B.sh: line 4: cd: /Users/myusername/AndroidStudioProjects/mpp-ios-android/native/KotlinIOS/../../SharedCode/build/xcode-frameworks: No such file or directory
/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KotlinIOS-ektaeprzdqunqygjxzrkmpdfyoyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/KotlinIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinIOS.build/Script-47729E7122F480EB00B9B36B.sh: line 5: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Being a novice at both Kotlin and app development, I'm not sure how to debug this or how to proceed. It seems that `gradlew` is a wrapper around gradle which I have installed (since I was able to build the Android app), but perhaps I've done something else wrong.

I'm using XCode 12.0 beta 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the Android build: you need to build the framework library for iOS in Android Studio, with the gradle task `SharedCode/Tasks/build/packForXcode`. This was failing for me (hence the missing directory error in XCode) because I hadn't moved Xcode to the `Applications` directory, which is where the gradle script expects to find the `xcodebuild` executable. Moving Xcode.app to `Applications` and running the `packForXcode` gradle task allowed me to build and simulate the app correctly in iOS.

Comment: Awesome. `./gradlew packForXcode` worked for me! Thanks!